# Как подрубить проверку паролей на бота в телеграмм на библиотеке telebot

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Вообще пишу бота для итогового проекта и тут мне надо сделать чтобы когда человек писал команду /check просило ввести пароль и проверяло соответствует ли он A-z 1-99 и символы вот код:

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=('check'))

def check(message):
    mess6 = f'Данная функция может определить сложность пароля, если пароль будет легкий воспользуйтесь командой /generate.'
    mess7 = f'Введите пароль...'
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, mess6, parse_mode='html')
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, mess7, parse_mode='html')
    if (r'^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*d)(?=.*[@$!%*?&])[A-Za-z\d@$!%*?&]{8,}$') == message.text:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Пароль надежный.', parse_mode='html')
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Пароль не надежен (не соответствует протоколу безопасности(A-Z, a-z, 1-99, @#$)) используйте /generate', parse_mode='html')
```

Оно и работает, но проверяет команду /check и перестает работать[image: Вот так], подскажите как сделать чтобы оно просило ввести пароль, и только после ввода проверяло его на символы, буду оченньь благодарен!

---

Зацикливается< и по факту работать невозможно
[image: (((]

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй так:

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=('check'))
def check(message):
    mess6 = f'Данная функция может определить сложность пароля, если пароль будет легкий воспользуйтесь командой /generate.'
    mess7 = f'Введите пароль...'
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, mess6, parse_mode='html')
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, mess7, parse_mode='html')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, check_password)

def check_password(message):
    password = message.text
    if (r'^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*d)(?=.*[@$!%*?&])[A-Za-z\d@$!%*?&]{8,}$') == password:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Пароль надежный.', parse_mode='html')
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Пароль не надежен (не соответствует протоколу безопасности(A-Z, a-z, 1-99, @#$)) используйте /generate', parse_mode='html')
```

Comment: Не работает( бот просто зацикливается